# Detect paragraph breaks in an XML-converted PDF (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, lxml

I have this PDF file that has those "long" whitespaces (highlighted in yellow in the image below). My goal is to detect them so I can separate the text segments around those whitespaces.

[image: n XML]

So far, my trials haven't been totally unsuccessful- since the XML returns a "bounding box" attribute (example: `bbox="68.031,553.639,76.375,566.366"`), that has four values (x1, y1, x2, y2), I could find out more or less the distance I was looking for doing x1 - x1 of the preceding element. But the output is not great and I'm sure there is a simpler answer to my problem than the one I have.

The output I get doesn't keep whitespaces and doesn't take into account line breaks. But doesn't even take into account paragraph breaks (image below):

[image]

Which need to take into account not x1 of the `bbox` attribute, but probably the y position, but I don't know how to deal with it.

This is my code:

```
import lxml.etree as etree

parser = etree.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True)
tree = etree.parse('fe3.xml', parser)
root = tree.getroot()

# Get the first BBox value as float
# Return null if not found
def getBBoxFirstValue(line):
    if line is not None:
        bb = line.attrib.get('bbox')
        if bb is not None:
            try:
                return float(bb.split(",")[0])
            except ValueError:
                pass
    return None


new_line        = None
previous_bb     = None

for x in tree.xpath('//text'):
    # Get current bb value
    bb = getBBoxFirstValue(x)
    # Check current and past values aren't empty
    if bb is not None and previous_bb is not None:
        #print(bb, previous_bb, (bb-previous_bb))
        #print(abs(bb-previous_bb))
        # If distance with preview bb > 10
        if (bb - previous_bb) > 20 or (bb - previous_bb) < -1000:
            # If new_line isn't empty: it's inserted into parent tag at position of current tag

            if new_line is not None:
                x.getparent().insert(x.getparent().index(x), new_line)
            # A new "new_line" element is created
            new_line = etree.Element("new_line")

        # If the new line isn't not (e.g. one distance > 10 has been already found)
        if new_line is not None:
            new_line.append(x)

    # Keep latest non empty BBox 1st value
    if bb is not None:
        previous_bb = bb

# Add last new_line element if not null
if new_line is not None:
    tree.xpath('//text')[-1].getparent().append(new_line)


newtree = etree.tostring(root, encoding='utf-8', pretty_print=True)
#newtree = newtree.decode("UTF-8")
print(newtree)
with open("output.xml", "wb") as f:
    f.write(newtree)
```

My input file is here: [link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dersuchendee/TESI/master/fe3.xml)

The output I get is here: [link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dersuchendee/TESI/master/output.xml)

EDIT:

For clarification, the XML input is like this:

Consider the text tags having the "`bbox`" attributes

```
<pages>
 <page>
  <textbox>
   <textline>
    <text> a </text>
    <text> b </text>
    <text> c </text>
   </textline>
   <textline>
    <text> d </text>
  </textbox>
  <textbox>
   <textline>
    <text> e </text>
    <text> f </text>
   </textline>
  </textbox>
 </page>
</pages>
```

The output I would like is:

```
<pages>
 <page>
  <textbox>
   <textline>
   <new_line>
    <text> a </text>
    <text> b </text>
   </new_line>
   <new_line>
    <text> c </text>
   </new_line>
   </textline>
   <textline>
   <new_line>
    <text> d </text>
   </new_line>
  </textbox>
  <textbox>
   <textline>
   <new_line>
    <text> e </text>
    <text> f </text>
    </new_line>
   </textline>
  </textbox>
 </page>
</pages>
```

But the output I get is:

```
<pages>
 <page>
  <textbox>
   <textline>
   <new_line>
    <text> a </text>
    <text> b </text>
   </new_line>
   </textline>
   <textline>
   <new_line>
    <text> c </text>
    <text> d </text>
   </new_line>
  </textbox>
  <textbox>
   <textline>
   <new_line>
    <text> e </text>
    <text> f </text>
    </new_line>
   </textline>
  </textbox>
 </page>
</pages>
```

So what happens with my code is that the "textbox" is not properly preserved.

Comment: For text with different values of X and the same value of Y, they are on one line, and the value of X represents its order. You should give a simplified input and the output you expect as an example.

Comment: I added an edit for clarification, of course since the real XML is huge and it's not good for a sample because the sample would be too long, I tried to be as clear as possible with what I want to achieve. Let me know if it's clearer now!

Comment: Your text doesn’t include any bbox attributes :-(

Comment: It was an example I made up because unfortunately the real one is too long! Would you prefer it if I put them in?

Comment: The full input text is there as a link

Comment: If `bbox` attributes are needed to reproduce the problem, then the XML examples **in the question** should have them. As I have said before, please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

The modification function of this library is a little weak. Try to see if it works.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc,req,utils
html = '''
<pages>
 <page>
  <textbox>
   <textline>
    <text> a </text>
    <text> b </text>
    <text> c </text>
   </textline>
   <textline>
    <text> d </text>
  </textbox>
  <textbox>
   <textline>
    <text> e </text>
    <text> f </text>
   </textline>
  </textbox>
 </page>
</pages>'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
first = doc.getElement('textline').getElement('text') # Get the first
first.repleaceSelf('<new_line>\n'+first.outerHtml)
next = first.getNext(tag='text') # Get next 
while next:
  tmp = next.next
  if next.text == 'c': # Your condition
    next.repleaceSelf('</new_line>\n<new_line>\n' + next.outerHtml)

  if not tmp or tmp.tag != "text": # The last one
    next.repleaceSelf(next.outerHtml + '\n</new_line>')
    tmp = doc.getElement('text', start=next._end)
    if tmp:
      tmp.repleaceSelf('<new_line>\n'+tmp.outerHtml)
  else:
    tmp = doc.getElement('text', start=next._end)
  next = tmp
print (doc.html)
```

Result:

```
<pages>
 <page>
  <textbox>
   <textline>
    <new_line>
<text> a </text>
    <text> b </text>
    </new_line>
<new_line>
<text> c </text>
</new_line>
   </textline>
   <textline>
    <new_line>
<text> d </text>
</new_line>
  </textbox>
  <textbox>
   <textline>
    <new_line>
<text> e </text>
    <text> f </text>
</new_line>
   </textline>
  </textbox>
 </page>
</pages>
```